# How to compare start and end time with current time in php?

Tags: php

```
$startTime = str_replace(":", "", 11:30);
$endTime = str_replace(":", "", 16:00);
$currentTime = str_replace(":", "", date('H:i'));

if ($currentTime >= $startTime) 
{
    $buttons = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Start Exam</a>';
}
else if($currentTime < $startTime)
{
    $buttons = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Please wait till start time..</a>';
}
else if($currentTime <= $endTime)
{
    $buttons = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Exam Over</a>';
}
```

In the above code. What happen now when `start time and current time` is equal or `current time` is greater then `start time` then it show `start exam` but it not working properly. So, How can I compare start and end time with current time? Please help.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize dates variables as DateTime and set the time. For example this

```
$startTime = (new DateTime())->setTime(11, 30,0);
$endTime = (new DateTime())->setTime(16, 0, 0);
$currentTime = new DateTime();
if($currentTime >= $endTime )
{
    $buttons = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Exam Over</a>';
}
else if ($currentTime >= $startTime) 
{
    $buttons = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Start Exam</a>';
}
else if($currentTime < $startTime)
{
    $buttons = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Please wait till start time..</a>';
}
```

Here is a full playground
https://tehplayground.com/O8vPv3ZExM4U7AtY

Answer (score 0):

If you are used to in **Carbon** package then you can easily do it using below code

for installation of Carbon package use

```
composer require nesbot/carbon
```

Add autoload file at the top.

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Carbon\Carbon;
```

Run below code to find time difference.

```
$start  = new Carbon('2018-10-04 15:00:03');
$end    = new Carbon(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
You may use

$start->diff($end)->format('%H:%I:%S');
```

Hope that, this will solve your problem as well.

See this code that I modified for you.

```
$startTime = str_replace(":", ":", '11:30');
$endTime = str_replace(":", ":", '16:00');
$currentTime = str_replace(":", "", date('H:i'));


if ($currentTime >= $startTime) {
    $buttons = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Start Exam</a>';
} else if ($currentTime < $startTime) {
    $buttons = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Please wait till start time..</a>';
} else if ($currentTime <= $endTime) {
    $buttons = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Exam Over</a>';
}

echo $buttons;
```

Comment: I am changing my code actually it's working only second condition and not working at exam over condition

Comment: Your time convention is not correct for comparing in php

Comment: I am little bit confuse your code `$startTime = str_replace(":", ":", '11:30');` what are you doing here

Answer (score 0):

I think you should convert the dates into timestamps and then compare the dates.

```php
$startTime = strtotime("11:30");
$endTime = strtotime("16:00");
$currentTime = strtotime(date('H:i'));
```